# Performance: XmlReader or LINQ to XML

Tags: .net, xml, performance, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I have a 150 MB XML file which is used as DB in my project. Currently I'm using `XmlReader` to read content from it. I want to know if it is better to use `XmlReader` or LINQ to XML for this scenario.

Note that I'm searching for an item in this XML and display search result, so it can take a long time or just a moment.

Comment: I think you are misusing XML here. Do not use it as a db. 150 MB? :o Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154499/linq-to-xml-vs-xmlreader

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want performance use XMLReader. It doesn't read the whole file and build the DOM tree in memory. It instead, reads the file from disk and gives you back each node it finds on the way.

With a quick google search I found a performance comparison of XmlReader, LINQ to XML and XmlDocument.Load.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130517114458/http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html

Answer (score 9):

I would personally look at using Linq to Xml utilizing the streaming techniques outlined in the Microsoft help file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx#Y1392

Here's a quick benchmark test reading from a 200mb xml file with a simple filter:

```cs
var xmlFilename = "test.xml";

//create test xml file
var initMemoryUsage = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var rand = new Random();
var testDoc = new XStreamingElement("root", //in order to stream xml output XStreamingElement needs to be used for all parent elements of collection so no XDocument
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(idx => new XElement("child", new XAttribute("id", rand.Next(0, 1000))))
);
testDoc.Save(xmlFilename);
var outStat = String.Format("{0:f2} sec {1:n0} kb //linq to xml ouput streamed", timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, (GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - initMemoryUsage) / 1024);

//linq to xml not streamed
initMemoryUsage = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
timer.Restart();
var col1 = XDocument.Load(xmlFilename).Root.Elements("child").Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("id") < 10).Select(e => (int)e.Attribute("id")).ToArray();
var stat1 = String.Format("{0:f2} sec {1:n0} kb //linq to xml input not streamed", timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, (GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - initMemoryUsage) / 1024);

//xmlreader
initMemoryUsage = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
timer.Restart();
var col2 = new List<int>();
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilename))
{
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("child"))
    {
        reader.MoveToAttribute("id");
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
        if (value < 10)
            res2.Add(value);
    }
}
var stat2 = String.Format("{0:f2} sec {1:n0} kb //xmlreader", timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, (GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - initMemoryUsage) / 1024);

//linq to xml streamed
initMemoryUsage = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
timer.Restart();
var col3 = StreamElements(xmlFilename, "child").Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("id") < 10).Select(e => (int)e.Attribute("id")).ToArray();
var stat3 = String.Format("{0:f2} sec {1:n0} kb //linq to xml input streamed", timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, (GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - initMemoryUsage) / 1024);

//util method
public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamElements(string filename, string elementName)
{
    using (var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(filename))
    {
        while (reader.Name == elementName || reader.ReadToFollowing(elementName))
            yield return (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
    }
}
```

And here's the processing time and memory usage on my machine:

```
11.49 sec 225 kb      // linq to xml ouput streamed

17.36 sec 782,312 kb  // linq to xml input not streamed
6.52 sec 1,825 kb     // xmlreader
11.74 sec 2,238 kb    // linq to xml input streamed
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a few benchmark tests to establish exactly what the situation is for you, and take it from there... Linq2XML introduces a lot of flexibility...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need to write your own simple benchmarks to find the answer as it varies from case to case.  The easiest way to do this is to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) as a Nuget Package in one of the following apps.  BenchmarkDotNet allows you to measure both the Memory allocation as well as the timings of each method.  It is FAR more advanced than any trivial solution using a Stopwatch and all of the .NET Teams use it to measure the code that goes into .NET!

- A simple Console app
- LinqPad (my favorite). There is a free and a Premium version that is reasonably priced!
- [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

**In all cases, you MUST build and run the test program in Release/Optimized mode (and preferably from outside any debugger).**

Please post back your findings.